# Is there a standard for use case specifications?

Tags: standards, use-case

I've been discussing about [whether "logging in" is a *use case*](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.7340.13) and I've been wondering: is there some "official" standard where to look up the definition of a use case or what the point of a use case specification is?

Comment: Nope, there is no official rigorous definition for terms like that. The best you can hope for are software methodology books that attempt to give a more precise explanation (of which I'm sure there are many).

Comment: The point of a use case is to describe... well, a use case, a business scenario which your system enables.  If you have a nice, coherent collection of these, you have a good overall description of what your system is supposed to do, which makes it easier to build it, yes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question asks whether or not there's a standard definition for such term in the context of software engineering. I'm not sure how another unofficial definition from you is helping. :/

Comment: Your last sentence includes the words "what the point of a use case specification is."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, if you take the words out of context I guess you can create your own question and then your own answer. The same sentence begins with "is there some 'official' standard where to look up..." though.

Comment: No, there's no official standard.  There are lots of things in software development that are not covered by some governing body.  Have a look here: http://alistair.cockburn.us/get/2465

Comment: Arguably, logging in, by itself, isn't a use case in itself.  That's on the basis that it isn't the user's goal in using the system.  It's just the first part of the interaction.  It gets messy, though, if the user wants to do multiple things, but only needs to log in once.  But you can create a sub-use-case, and use an "include" relationship to pull it in from the real use case.

Answer (score 3):

There is a UML specification, published by the OMG, that defines use cases.  See section 18 of [UML 2.5](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF).  However, it's all very technical, and says very little about what use cases are for, or how to identify them.

[image]

Comment: And the downside of UML is everyone thinks they understand it but nobody is ever in agreement on how to use it.

Comment: @MetaFight - No one agrees on how to use UML in general or they never agree on how to implement a specific case?

Comment: I've never meet two people who agreed on how to document the same thing in UML.

Comment: Customer, Administrator and Bank are too skinny.

Comment: @user61852 a classic case of needing more freehand circles.